# How to sum and multiply two class instances

Tags: python, python-3.x

As i said in topic i need to create class that can be sum by other class and also multiply. Below present expected result and code behaviour.

```
v1 = Vector([1, 2, 1, 5]) - class 1 called Vector
v2 = Vector([2, 3, 1, 4]) - class 2 called Vector

# [1+2, 2+3, 1+1, 5+4] - expected sums
v3 = v1 + v2
v3.get_vals()
[3, 5, 2, 9] - expected result

# 1*2 + 2*3 + 1*1 + 5*4 - multiplication
v1 * v2
29
```

Comment: if you want to multiple two list and add two list then you can use map method like this but if you want this for object then given solution is fine. __list(map(lambda x: x[0]+x[1], zip(a,b)))__

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define `__add__`, `__mul__` and other dunder methods.

For example:

```
class Vector:
    def __init__(self, arr):
        self.arr = list(arr)
    
    def __add__(self, other):
        return Vector(a + b for a, b in zip(self.arr, other.arr))
    
    def __mul__(self, other):
        return sum(a * b for a, b in zip(self.arr, other.arr))
    
    def get_vals(self):
        return self.arr

v1 = Vector([1, 2, 1, 5])
v2 = Vector([2, 3, 1, 4])

v3 = v1 + v2
assert [3, 5, 2, 9] == v3.get_vals()

assert v1 * v2 == 29
```

I do suggest using packages such as [numpy](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html) for that instead of reinventing the wheel.

Comment: It might be worth defining `Vector.__iter__` as well. Then you can zip `self` and `other` directly, instead of using the `arr` attribute. It also gives you a "copy constructor" for free: `v1 = Vector([1,2,3]); v2 = Vector(v1)`.

Comment: @chepner I agree, we can define plenty of more methods, including better representation with `__repr__`,  and implement the full `MutableSequence` abc. I do believe however the OP is attempting to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to break this down a little bit.

First you have Python's [magic methods](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-numeric-types) which allow any class to utilize operators like `+` or `*`.

Second you have [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) which will allow you to map elements from two (or more) iterables to each other.

Third [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) will allow a new list to be constructed in place with a forloop.

```py
class Vector:

    def __add__(self, other):
        return self.__class__([x + y for x, y in zip(self.values, other.values)])

    def __mul__(self, other):
        return self.__class__([x * y for x, y in zip(self.values, other.values)])
```

I would recommend using a helper method and the [`operator` library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html) to avoid duplicating bits of your code.

```py
class Vector:

    def new(self, other, operator_):
        return self.__class__([operator_(*x) for x in zip(self.values, other.values)])

    def __add__(self, other):
        return self.new(other, operator.add)

    def __mul__(self, other):
        return self.new(other, operator.mul)
```